# Transfering Folder using batch scripting in windows from a specified list

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, file-copying

I want to transfer some specific files from a location to another in Windows using batch.

I have been successfull when I enter individual file names or about 10 at a time but I haven't been able to successfully introduce a file list that can be read whiwh will be used to identy the names of files to be copied.

```bash
@echo off

set "source_dir=F:\dump"
set "destination_dir=C:\Users\retire"

rem List of files to copy
set  "file_list="Bonded* Done* Fish*"

rem Loop through the file list and copy each file
for %%F in (%file_list%) do (
    copy "%source_dir%\%%F" "%destination_dir%\%%F"
    echo Copied %%F to %destination_dir%
)

echo Copying completed.
```

Above works fine

```bash
@echo off

set "source_dir=F:\dump"
set "destination_dir=C:\Users\retire"

rem List of files to copy
set  "file_list="filelist.txt"

rem Loop through the file list and copy each file
for %%F in (%file_list%) do (
    copy "%source_dir%\%%F" "%destination_dir%\%%F"
    echo Copied %%F to %destination_dir%
)

echo Copying completed.`
```

Inside File List is

```
Bonded*
Done*
Fish*
```

This doesn't work.

I have been able to get some updates done but not sill getting an accurate result

```bash
@echo off

set "source_dir=source_dir=F:\dump"
set "ddestination_dir=C:\Users\retire"
set "file_list=file_list.txt"

rem Loop through each line in the file list and copy the corresponding file
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%F in ("%~dp0%file_list%") do (
    set "file_name=%%~F"
    echo This is the source %source_dir%\%file_name%

    rem Copy the file to the destination directory
    copy "%source_dir%\%file_name%" "%destination_dir%\%file_name%"

    echo Copied %file_name% to %destination_dir%
)

echo Copying completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a positive result after tinkering with the copy line.

Below is the final code.

It works perfectly :) :D :)

```
@echo off

set "source_dir=source_dir=F:\dump"
set "destination_dir=C:\Users\retire"
set "file_list=file_list.txt"

rem Loop through each line in the file list and copy the corresponding file
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%F in ("%~dp0%file_list%") do (
    set "file_name=%%~F"
    echo This is the source %source_dir%\%file_name%

    rem Copy the file to the destination directory

    copy "%source_dir%\%%F" "%destination_dir%\%%F"

    echo Copied %file_name% to %destination_dir%
)

echo Copying completed.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ```copy "%source_dir%\%%F" "%destination_dir%"``` rather than ```copy "%source_dir%\%%F" "%destination_dir%\%%F"```? Also you appear to be informing the end user that a file is being copied without even knowing if such a file exists! Similarly you're telling them that the file, existing or not, was copied without determining whether the action was successful!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**